# Triangle of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm just wondering to code something for fun.

I want to make a triangle of numbers. For example

```
1
12
123
1234
123
12
1
```

Number of line is chosen by the user. Like in this example the user input is 7.

If the user input is 5 than the outcome must be like that:

```
1
12
123
12
1
```

Thanks for your help people.

Comment: OK, good luck I guess... Let us know how it works.

Comment: haha that's not what I was looking for

Comment: try a nested for loop, followed by another

Comment: what's nested for loop? do you have an example?

Comment: oh thanks I got your point Jeremy but im not sure where to start :/

Comment: Start with writing a function or bit of code that for any whole number n writes n starson a line and then moves to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty simple, first you need to get input from the console and store it in a variable. easiest way to do that is with the built in input function.

```
userinput = input("Enter number: ")
```

next you would obviously need to use a for loop that used the input, so

```
for i in range(0,int(userinput),1):
```

that will cause what ever code you have in it to loop until it reaches the number that was put in. and lastly to write to the console you use

```
print("insert text or variable here")
```

other than that its all math, it wouldn't be any fun if I did that for you :P
have fun!

Comment: and how would I do for the second, third (and  so on) for other columns?

Comment: So that is where the nested comes in. To print i stars, set up a for loop that goes from j equals 1 up to i, and print one star inside that loop. Or make a function that takes a number as a parameter and inside that function make a loop. The way @thebestnightsky has set it up, you might want j to go up to i+1. Also the loop above will get you only as far as the middle of the figure. You need to have a for loop that goes back down, too (and again a loop inside that loop)